# 'firestore' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a new project using firebase. I've created 2 files,

> firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/storage";
import "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "x",
  authDomain: "x",
  projectId: "x",
  storageBucket: "x",
  messagingSenderId: "x",
  appId: "x",
  measurementId: "x",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase;
```

> and App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import firebase from "./firebase";

export default function App() {
  const [urlVideo, setUV] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    getRoom();
    console.log("TEST");
  }, []);

  const getRoom = async () => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("abc")
      .add({
        room: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
        createdAt: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Room added!");
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

and when I run my project, I am getting this error. Please refer to the image below.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP0eM.png)

idk why this is happened, because I already have multiple projects with firebase before, and I've compared with another project (the code) and realized there's no difference with my last project using firebase.

I'm using

> "firebase": "^8.7.0",

can you guys help me? thanks a lot!

Comment: Well it is pretty obvious, that you're trying to use `firestore`, but you never defined `firestore`

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment.. i think i got the problem..

Comment: You should consider using a proper editor that will notify you of such errors while you code.

Comment: Yeaa, i think you are right! thanks for you advice..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
createdAt: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
           ^^^^^^^^^
```

The namespace is not defined anywhere so you would have to export that too.

Refactor the **firebase.js** like this:

```
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

const firestoreNamespace = firebase.firestore

export {firebase, firestoreNamespace};
```

**App.js:**

```
import { firebase, firestoreNamespace } from "./firebase"

// Now you can use the namespace like this
createdAt: firestoreNamespace.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

Comment: Dudeeee, you have the perfect eye :)) yea that's the problem! thanks a lot!