# Error when trying to add timestamps to comment section for social media web app using firebase

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

When trying to setup timestamps for a comment system for users on my social media web app I get the error:

"TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["default"].firestore.FieldValue.serverTimeStamp is not a function. (In 'firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["default"].firestore.FieldValue.serverTimeStamp()', 'firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["default"].firestore.FieldValue.serverTimeStamp' is undefined)"

This is the section of code where the errors are coming from:

```
    const postComment = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    db.collection("posts").doc(postId).collection("comments").add({
        text: comment,
        username: username.displayName,
        timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimeStamp(),
    });
    setComment('');
}
```

If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it.

screenshot:

![screenshot] (https://cdn.glitch.com/0f2dd307-0d28-4fe9-9ef9-db84277033dd%2FScreenshot%202021-07-18%20at%2011.36.14.png?v=1626604625641)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there's a typo. It's `serverTimestamp` and not `serverTimeStamp`.

Also that `firebase.js` file (visible in screenshot) is where you initialize Firebase, then I'll say export the timestamp from there itself as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68220434/13130697).

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/firestore"

const firestore = firebase.firestore()
const serverTimestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

export {firestore, serverTimestamp}
```

Now you can easily use `serverTimestamp()` directly in any other components.

The `username` seems to be a string:

```
db.collection("posts").doc(postId).collection("comments").add({
  text: comment,
  username, //username.displayName,
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ remove this
  timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
});
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed the timestamp but not I get another error that says: "FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field username in document posts/PbWx6MmqM5vHfjXZIAee/comments/Z5DnFTPhLCH7mFAIYc4Y)" here's a screenshot: ![screenshot] (https://cdn.glitch.com/0f2dd307-0d28-4fe9-9ef9-db84277033dd%2FScreenshot%202021-07-18%20at%2012.43.50.png?v=1626608690720)

Comment: @shange the error literally says username field is undefined. Can you please share complete code so we can see where username is coming from ?

Comment: ![screenshot] (https://cdn.glitch.com/0f2dd307-0d28-4fe9-9ef9-db84277033dd%2FScreenshot%202021-07-18%20at%2012.57.28.png?v=1626609512581) firebase database screenshot you can see the username is there clearly

Comment: @shange in your code... please share your code. Where is `username` initialized?

Comment: Ok I uploaded my Post.js file to glitch so you can see the full code, see it here: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/post-js

Comment: @shange I see `username` is being passed as a parameter `function Post( { postId, username, caption, imageUrl }) `  but I can't see from where that value of `username` is coming. Can you please share the code snippet from where you are passing that? Maybe in another file where you use `<Post>` component ?

Comment: It's probably in App.js, I've added it to glitch: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/app-and-post-js

Comment: @shange yes it seems to be a string. Please try update answer.

Comment: @Dhamaraj Thank you this worked but the spacing between comments is too small even though I set comment padding to 20px in the css, see screenshot: https://cdn.glitch.com/0f2dd307-0d28-4fe9-9ef9-db84277033dd%2FScreenshot%202021-07-18%20at%2013.34.00.png?v=1626611688248

Comment: @shange glad it worked. You can accept the answer by clicking the ✔ icon :) The CSS issue seems completely different than the original so it's better to ask a separate question with relevant tags :)

Comment: Hello I just realised removing displayName worked but it is not the solution because I need displayName to show which users are commenting on which post otherwise all comments look like they are from the user who posted the image

Comment: @shange isn't the `username` itself the name? Because that seems to be a string. Try `console.log(username)` and share the response maybe.

Comment: I have tried console.log(username) in the terminal but it gives the error syntax error near unexpected token `username' , see screenshot here: https://cdn.glitch.com/0f2dd307-0d28-4fe9-9ef9-db84277033dd%2FScreenshot%202021-07-18%20at%2017.21.52.png?v=1626625464954

Comment: @shange you add the `console.log()` statement in your code.. not in the terminal

Comment: @Dharamaj I have added the console.log(username) statement in my code but nothing has shown up in the browser screen, screenshot: https://cdn.glitch.com/0f2dd307-0d28-4fe9-9ef9-db84277033dd%2FScreenshot%202021-07-18%20at%2017.30.34.png?v=1626625948567

Comment: is this what you wanted to see? https://cdn.glitch.com/0f2dd307-0d28-4fe9-9ef9-db84277033dd%2FScreenshot%202021-07-18%20at%2018.01.12.png?v=1626627719031

Answer (score 0):

It's "serverTimestamp()" there is no capital S.. But if that isn't the problem try importing the serverTimestamp inside your firebase.js or where ever you are initializing the firebase app

For the username field being invalid, it is because in firebase there is no username, it's displayName and it's inside the user object and not the username object

```
const postComment = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    db.collection("posts").doc(postId).collection("comments").add({
        text: comment,
        username: user.displayName,
        timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
    setComment('');
}
```